# Suggestion: Down vote if you have already answer or made comment in a question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, voting, down-votes

I would like to suggest stackoverflow to fix the down vote system.

Currently, someone can be down voted so so so easily by users that they don't know the problem and or the don't answer questions etc.

Let me give you an example,

**The problem:**

**Example 1:**

If user1 asks a question and user2 answers that question, user3 can down vote user2's answer because he/she doesn't get it. Also, user3 will not even make an answer in this question. 
The result is that MAYBE users2's answer is correct, and user3 who is a simple reader of the question with or without knowledge down vote user2 on purpose. **What a fair voting system....**

**Example 2:**

User 1 makes a question and user2 just down vote it without suggest with a comment for a fixing. Result: User1 down voted without even know the reason and he can not what to fix in his question. Again, **what a fair voting system....**

**This is totally unfair.**

**Why is this unfair?**

If someone wants to down vote he **must answer** or **make a comment** somewhere in  the question/answer. If he didn't, he has not any intention to help or he has not the proper skills and knowledge to answer the question. 
In this case:

1. First of all, why stackoverflow allows him to down vote ?
2. and secondly, why is he the correct judge to down vote someone's intention for helping?

Does it look fair for you?

**The Solution:**

**Example 3:**

User1 makes a question, and the question is not so good. Nobody can down vote it except if they make a comment or answer. In this case, user2 is FORCED to comment it and after to down vote it.   **Fair voting system!**

**Example 4:**

User1 makes a question and user2 answers it. User3 which think that this answer is not good wants to down vote it. But he can not because he didn't answer or made a comment. So, user3 make a comment in user2's answer that "it is poor and it lacks of research" and after user3 down vote it. Now, user2 can understand his mistake and he can FIX his answer with more research, etc.  **Fair voting system!**

I found that someone has already point that issue 6 years ago: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?rq=1)
However, you can not just "suggest" to someone under an amount of reputation to add a comment to explain why he down-vote.

First of all, **everyone** must explain why he/she down-vote. This is what someone can call **fair community**.

Also, the problem is not on if you encourage someone to explain his/her down-vote, but to force him to explain the reason that he/she down-vote it.

Answer (score 11):

This has been discussed to death in the past, but to address your key points.

> 1. First of all, why stackoverflow allows him to down vote ?

Because that's how Stack Exchange works. Votes make good content rise to the top, and bad content fall to the bottom. And they actually did provide feedback in the process, by indicating the content may have issues.

> 2. and secondly, why is he the correct judge to down vote someone's intention for helping?

Because they have earned the privileged of downvoting, and are exercising it to help in the content sorting process. Their votes are theirs to use as they see fit, within reason (no serial voting).

> Does it look fair for you?

Yes.